# Redirecting to Bot from URL

Tags: json, redirect, botframework, adaptive-cards, web-chat

I am working on a .Net core Bot application where I have created an adaptive card and when user clicks it would be redirected to a new URL. Once, redirected I want to add a functionality that after user posts in the URL, he should be redirected back to the BOT with the posted data. Can anyone guide me how to approach this. Below is the sample JSON we have created for redirecting user to URL.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "This card's action will open a URL"
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
      "title": "Action.OpenUrl",
      "url": "https://adaptivecards.io"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to add a functionality that after user posts in the URL, he should be redirected back to the BOT with the posted data"? What channel are you using? Are you using Web Chat? Are you expecting the new URL to open in the same browser tab that the Web Chat component was in? What would the user be "posting" in that new URL? Are you trying to say the user is filling out a form or something? Are you saying the new URL has a button that submits data and opens the site with Web Chat again? Can you create a flow chart or diagram that explains visually what you're trying to do?

Comment: Is Jos's answer acceptable?

Comment: I am using Directline Web chat. What I want to achieve is for example I send a request to chat bot say- Schedule a meeting, the Bot should redirect me to another URL which has all the details on scheduling meeting like name, list of attendees, time and date etc. The user would enter all the fields and then when user submits, the control is taken back to the Bot and the Bot is notified of all the data added by the user. The new URL which is to be opened which contains the form is a react component which contains form data for scheduling a meeting.

Comment: Is Jos's answer acceptable?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 1):

if you are asking about a **Teams bot** then you should follow the pattern for a [Bot Task Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-bots#:%7E:text=Task%20modules%20can%20be%20invoked%20from%20Microsoft%20Teams,and%20allow%20the%20user%20to%20interrupt%2Fcancel%20the%20sequence.)

1. Bot message + Card
2. Activate Task module (aka pop-up window)

   - task module can display another Adaptive Card
   - or a HTML page
3. Task Module completes and sends back info to your bot using `task/submit`