# Bot to web browser and back to bot

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a azure bot in C# that redirects the user to another application using adaptive card (action.openurl). I want the user to be redirected back to bot .
Please guide me

Comment: Are you working with Sharvani? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67871471/redirecting-to-bot-from-url

Comment: Are you still working on this?